# On change is not working in IE 11 using jQuery, but working in Firefox & Chrome

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm triggering "on" change function using jquery. It works perfectly fine in firefox and chrome.. But this is not getting triggered in IE 11. Here is my code

```
$("#newstaggered-carousel input[name='otherCity']").on('change', function() {
```

Comment: try `.on('input'`, I'm not sure it will work.

Comment: Note that this is an event listener, not an event trigger. Triggering an event is fire an event.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude then how it should be written. It should work in IE, Firefox & Chrome

Comment: @Nizam what is your HTML? According to this: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/998355 the event doesn't fires if is an indeterminate input. Please, share your html input code

Answer (score 0):

Try with the compatability set in the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```